# Select parent from child class name then add another class name to the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add another class name to a parent div of an article. 
I want to select 2 class names then add another class name to the parent. 
I'm pretty new to js/JQuery 
this is what i've not so far.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.random-1 .category-49').parent('div').addClass('double-width');
});
```

Comment: Since this is a JavaScript question rather than WP-specific, you'd be better off asking on StackOverflow or reading the jQuery docs. What you've coded so far will only select an element with class "category-49" within an element with class "random-1", so if you're trying to affect both, put them on 2 separate lines so it selects just elements with class "random-1" and gets the parent div, then adds the class you want, and the second line targets "category-49" to do the same.

Comment: Can you please also add your html code here and please describe with screenshot where exactly you want to add another class so I can help you.

Comment: Managed to work it out. I needed both of the classes to qualify not just one or the other.
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.random-1.category-49').parent('div').addClass('double-width');
});